# Add warning message in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django-rest-framework. I am building an employee scheduling application where I have a REST Api built with drf and frontend in angular. Below is one of my models and it's corrsponding serializer and viewset.

model:

```
class Eventdetail(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    is_daily_detail = models.BooleanField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event
```

serializer:

```
class LocationTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
         super(LocationTrackSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

     location = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='location_name', queryset=Location.objects.all())
     location_color = serializers.CharField(source='location.location_color', read_only=True)

     class Meta:
          model = Eventdetail
          fields = ('id','employee','location','location_color','start','end')
```

viewset:

```
class LocationTrackViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Eventdetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationTrackSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = request.user
        listOfThings = request.data['events']

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=listOfThings, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As you can see, this exposes event details of all employees. Now when new events are posted, I want to be able to find if the start and end times of posted events overlap with existing events and throw a warning message with info of overlapping events after creation. I still want to allow save but only return warnings after save. i am trying to figure out a way to do this. I looked at how to create validators, but I am not sure if that is how I should go about this. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by warning? Additional data along with serializer data, is that it?

Comment: @SachinKukreja Sorry, yes that is what I meant. If the newly posted event has overlapping dates with an existing event, then a message field that says 'overlaps with existing event'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field `warning_message` to the serializer as follows -

```
class LocationTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # rest of the code

    def get_warning_message(self, obj):
        warning_msg = ''

        # logic for checking overlapping dates
        # create a method `are_dates_overlapping` which takes
        # start and end date of the current obj and checks with all
        # others in queryset.
        overlap = are_dates_overlapping(obj.start, obj.end)
        if overlap:
            warning_msg = 'overlaps'

        return warning_msg

    warning_message = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Eventdetail
        fields = ('id','employee','location','location_color','start','end', 'warning_message')
```

Ref: [Serializer Method Field in DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)